# Is it possible to change gamemode or gametype while the server is running?

Tags: server-administration, counter-strike-global-offensive

I am in the process of configuring a Counterstrike: Global Offensive server and I was wondering if the game mode and game type can be changed on the fly, preferably from within the game by calling a vote, without restarting the server process?

Currently I am running the server in Classic Competitive mode but below is the combinations of game mode and game type which invoke the different play modes;

```
Mode                   game_mode    game_type
Classic Casual             0            0
Classic Competitive        0            1
Arms Race                  1            0
Demolition                 1            1
```

From the documentation I have read so far these are set as you launch the server process as follows;

```
srcds -game csgo -console -usercon +game_type 0 +game_mode 1 +mapgroup mg_bomb +map de_dust2
```

Is it possible to change gamemode or gametype while the server is running?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes it is quite possible to do this.  The issue is the game mode will not be enforced until a map change occurs.  So for instance entering the following in the console will give the desired effect:

```
rcon_password fooBarBaz  
rcon game_mode 1 (classic competitive)  
rcon changelevel de_any
```

This will change the game mode and change the current level thus enforcing the new game mode.  Of note this is based on my NFO server config (nuclear fallout hosting)

Comment: I really wish this was an in-game votable option.